# Dynamic Pivot -- Show Fields Only if Needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I'm running a small script in VB and I am trying to display only months that are between the startDate and endDate.  Here is my VB+SQL.  I think this is a SQL issue, not a VB issue.

```
Private Sub ChartData_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ChartData.Click


    'Initialize the objects before use
    Dim dataAdapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter()
    Dim dataSet As New DataSet
    Dim command As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim datatableMain As New System.Data.DataTable()
    Dim connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim DestName As String
    Dim VBstartDate As Date
    Dim VBendDate As Date
    Dim strSql As String

    MessageBox.Show("Please notice: it may take 1-2 minutes to product your report, depending on the volume of data selected!")

    'Assign your connection string to connection object
    connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=Server-Name;Initial Catalog=DB-Name;Integrated Security=True"
    command.Connection = connection
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    'You can use any command select

    VBstartDate = DatePickerStart.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
    VBendDate = DatePickerEnd.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")

    strSql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT Contact_ID, TB_Line, Deal_Balance, DATENAME(Month,[AsOfDate]) AS TheDate FROM [TBL_Deposit_HIST] Where [AsOfDate] >= '" & VBstartDate & "' and [AsOfDate] <= '" & VBendDate & "') AS P PIVOT (SUM(DEAL_BALANCE) FOR TheDate in (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)) AS PV;"
    command.CommandText = StrSql
    dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command

    'Dim f As FolderBrowserDialog = New FolderBrowserDialog
    Try
        'If f.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        'This section help you if your language is not English.
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")
        Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
        Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim oRange As Excel.Range

        oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing)
        oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)
        'oRange = oExcel.Range

        Dim columnLetter As String
        Dim dc As System.Data.DataColumn
        Dim dr As System.Data.DataRow
        Dim colIndex As Integer = 0
        Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0

        'Fill data to datatable
        connection.Open()
            dataAdapter.Fill(datatableMain)
            connection.Close()


            'Export the Columns to excel file
            For Each dc In datatableMain.Columns
                colIndex = colIndex + 1
                oSheet.Cells(1, colIndex) = dc.ColumnName
            Next

            'Export the rows to excel file
            For Each dr In datatableMain.Rows
                rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
                colIndex = 0
                For Each dc In datatableMain.Columns
                    colIndex = colIndex + 1
                    oSheet.Cells(rowIndex + 1, colIndex) = dr(dc.ColumnName)
                Next
            Next

        Dim LastRow As Long
        Dim LastColumn As Long
        Dim StrLastCol As String

        ' Find last row and last column
        With oSheet
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row
            LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlToLeft).Column
        End With

        ' Convert column number to column letter
        Select Case LastColumn
            Case 1 To 26
                StrLastCol = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32("A"c) + LastColumn - 1).ToString()
            Case 27 To 52
                StrLastCol = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32("a"c) + LastColumn - 27).ToString()
            Case Else
                StrLastCol = String.Empty
        End Select

        'create chart object
        Dim chartPage As Excel.Chart
        Dim xlCharts As Excel.ChartObjects
        Dim myChart As Excel.ChartObject
        Dim chartRange As Excel.Range

        xlCharts = oSheet.ChartObjects
        myChart = xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 300, 250)
        chartPage = myChart.Chart

        ' Set dynamic range
        chartRange = oSheet.Range("A1:" & StrLastCol & "25")
        chartPage.SetSourceData(Source:=chartRange)
        chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlColumnClustered

        'Set final path for saving Excel Report
        DestName = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) & "\Report.xls"

        oExcel.Visible = True
        oSheet.Columns.AutoFit()
        'Save file in final path
        oBook.SaveAs(DestName, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)


        'Release the objects
        ReleaseObject(oSheet)
            oBook.Close(False, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
            ReleaseObject(oBook)
            oExcel.Quit()
            ReleaseObject(oExcel)
            'Some time Office application does not quit after automation: 
            'so i am calling GC.Collect method.
            GC.Collect()

        MessageBox.Show("Export done successfully! You can find your report on your desktop!!")

        'End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    End Try

End Sub
```

For instance, this seems close.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
declare @startDate datetime
declare @endDate datetime        
set @startDate = '10/10/2017'
set @endDate = '11/30/2017'
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.AsOfDate) 
            FROM [TBL_Deposit_HIST] c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Contact_ID, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                SELECT Contact_ID,  
                Deal_Balance,
                AsOfDate
                from [TBL_Deposit_HIST]
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 SUM(Deal_Balance)
                WHERE AsOfDate BETWEEN (' + @cols + ') AND (' + @cols + ') 
            ) p '
execute(@query)
```

However, that gives me the following error.

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.
```

The script below does compile, but it gives me too broad a date range.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
declare @startDate datetime
declare @endDate datetime        
set @startDate = '10/10/2017'
set @endDate = '11/30/2017'
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.AsOfDate) 
            FROM [TBL_Deposit_HIST] c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Contact_ID, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                SELECT Contact_ID,  
                Deal_Balance,
                AsOfDate
                from [TBL_Deposit_HIST]
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 SUM(Deal_Balance)
                for AsOfDate in (' + @cols + ')

            ) p '
execute(@query)
```

I think I need a Where and Between, but I can't get it working just right.

The results are displayed in Excel.  The DatePicker works fine and the SQL literally does what I tell it to do, but it displays ALL MONTHS for the year, even if I choose, let's say 9/1/17 to 11/20/17.  Is there a way to may the pivot fields dynamic, along with the dynamic dates.  Or do I have to run it as-is, and delete any columns in Excel where row 2 is empty, or some such thing?  I want to display only the data between the startDate and endDate.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Once you want to display the months between two dates, you should make sure to include the year because you might have a case that the dates are from `25 Nov 2017` to `15 Mar 2018` for example.

I designed a sample data that will show the Month  as `[yyyy-MMM]`

**Explanation**

1. Build the columns for all months between `@start` and `@end`, and you can skip this by only finding the exact months used by applying the query to your table with where clause.
2. Get all the data with formatting the date as `[yyyy-MMM]` from your table, and for this I used the `report` cte
3. Apply the pivot

Query

```
if exists( select 1 from #data)
     drop table #data
create  table #data(
   Id int not null identity(1,1),
   AsOfDate datetime,
   Balance money
)

insert into #data(AsOfDate,Balance)
values ('11 Oct 2017',1854.24),
       ('15 Sep 2017',1554.25),
       ('11 Sep 2017',1554.14),
       ('09 May 2017',255.55),
       ('27 Sep 2017',145.15)

  declare @start datetime = '05 May 2017',
          @end datetime ='17 Sep 2017'

 declare @cols varchar(max),
         @query varchar(max);

with months as(
    select @start as [Date], quotename(format(@start,'yyyy MMM')) as [Month]
    union all
    select dateadd(month,1,[Date]),quotename(format(dateadd(month,1,[Date]),'yyyy MMM'))
    from months
    where [Date] < @end
)

 select @cols = stuff((select ',' + [Month]
                   from months
                   order by [Date]
                   for xml path(''),type).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')


 select @query = ';with report as(
                select sum(Balance) [Balance],format(AsOfDate,''yyyy MMM'') as [Date]
                from #data
                where AsOfDate between ''' + cast(@start as varchar) + ''' and ''' + cast( @end as varchar) + '''
                group by format(AsOfDate,''yyyy MMM''))
            select ' + @cols + '
            from report 
            pivot(sum(Balance) for [Date] in('+ @cols +')) p'

exec (@query)
```

Output result

```
2017 May    2017 Jun    2017 Jul    2017 Aug    2017 Sep    2017 Oct
255.55  NULL    NULL    NULL    3108.39 NULL
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

does including the WHERE clause with the select:

```
SELECT Contact_ID,  
                Deal_Balance,
                AsOfDate
from [TBL_Deposit_HIST]
WHERE AsOfDate BETWEEN (' + @cols + ') AND (' + @cols + ')
```

...not work?

Comment: I tried that before posting.  I though that would work, but I get this: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

Comment: Thanks Monah.  It seems like that could be the solution.  Can you help me adapt your code to fit my specific scenario?  I tried several things, but couldn't get it working.  Thanks.